# Transform - Custom Code - runs great w 2 filters but want 3+ filters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-glue

In AWS Glue Studio, I created a "Transform - Custom code" to filter some records based on - eventually - many columns, keeping only records that *violate* any column not validating correctly so the log can be looked at to determine invalid values.

The following code works to filter based only on two columns:

```
def MyTransform (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
    df = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()
    from pyspark.sql import functions as sf

    dfFirstRule = df.filter((df['Cardholder_ID'] < 3911539932589))
    dfFirstRule = dfFirstRule.withColumn('invalid_cardholder_id', sf.lit('true'))

    dfSecondRule = df.filter((df['Patient_Effective_Date'] < 20230101))
    dfSecondRule = dfSecondRule.withColumn('invalid_patient_effective_date', sf.lit('true'))

    outputDf = dfFirstRule.unionByName(dfSecondRule, allowMissingColumns=True)

    output = DynamicFrame.fromDF(outputDf, glueContext, "output")
    return (DynamicFrameCollection({"out0": output}, glueContext))
```

If I want to add another rule (for now and later many rules), how can I restructure this so that it is more elegant and efficient to handle more than just two rules?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did it!

```
def MyTransform (glueContext, dfc) -> DynamicFrameCollection:
    rules = [
        {'column': 'Cardholder_ID', 'operator': '<', 'value': 3911539932589, 'errors': 'invalid_cardholder_id'},
        {'column': 'Patient_Effective_Date', 'operator': '<', 'value': 20230101, 'errors': 'invalid_patient_effective_date'},
        {'column': 'Patient_Term_Reason', 'operator': '<', 'value': 1, 'errors': 'invalid_patient_term_reason'},
        {'column': 'Patient_Term_Date', 'operator': '<', 'value': 20230101, 'errors': 'invalid_patient_term_date'}
        # more rules here
        ]
    df = dfc.select(list(dfc.keys())[0]).toDF()
    from pyspark.sql import functions as sf
    outputDf = None
    for rule in rules:
        filteredDf = df.filter((df[rule['column']] < rule['value']))
        filteredDf = filteredDf.withColumn(rule['errors'], sf.lit('true'))
        if outputDf is None:
            outputDf = filteredDf
        else:
            outputDf = outputDf.unionByName(filteredDf, allowMissingColumns=True)
    output = DynamicFrame.fromDF(outputDf, glueContext, "output")
    return (DynamicFrameCollection({"out0": output}, glueContext))
```